# Qu'est-ce que la réduplication du clitique sujet veut dire dans les phrases déclaratives ?

Tags: grammaire, sujet

Bonjour, j'ai trouvé une phrase [dans la Wikipédie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyc%C3%A9e_(%C3%A9cole_philosophique)) :

> La nouveauté dans les travaux du Lycée et dans le monde grec de cette époque réside dans l’intérêt grandissant pour la recherche empirique : pour la première fois, l’observation et l’étude précise de la nature et des événements humains président à des travaux scientifiques. Les recherches historiques et chronologiques effectuées dans les archives politiques et administratives des archontes sont à l’origine de plusieurs traités : Sur les poètes, sur les concours des Grandes Dionysies et des Lénéennes ou encore Sur les problèmes homériques. Ces travaux font du Lycée, sous l’impulsion d’Aristote, le foyer fondateur de la poétique, de la chronologie littéraire et de cette discipline moderne que nous appelons la philologie. Dans le domaine des sciences de la nature, favorisées par les découvertes faites par l’expédition d’Alexandre en Asie, le Lycée innove aussi totalement. Ainsi ce qui est dit des éléphants dans l’Histoire des Animaux suppose la bataille d'Arbèles en 331, où les Grecs en virent pour la première fois. Ainsi encore, **les jeunes étudiants purent-ils pratiquer** l’examen minutieux et la dissection des animaux et des plantes, dont témoignent abondamment les cours de biologie qui nous sont parvenus sous le titre de Recherches sur les Animaux, Parties des Animaux et Génération des Animaux, qui sont des œuvres de collaboration entre le Maître et de jeunes membres de l’école …

Il me semble que j'ai déjà vu cet usage quelque part sans jamais comprendre sa signification. Quelle est la différence entre cette tournure et le simple « *les jeunes étudiants purent pratiquer …* » ? Pourquoi une construction plus complexe a-t-elle été employée ? Comment *sent-on* la phrase qui a été construite là ? Merci.

De plus, j'ai trouvé un autre cas mais je ne suis pas sûr que ce soit la même chose :

> Lis l'amour dans mes yeux et non pas dans les nombres
> Ne grise pas ton cœur de leurs philtres anciens
> Les ruines à midi ne sont que des décombres
> C'est l'heure où nous avons deux ombres
> Pour mieux embarrasser l'art des sciomanciens
>
> **La nuit plus que le jour aurait-elle des charmes**
> Honte à ceux qu'un ciel pur ne fait pas soupirer
> Honte à ceux qu'un enfant tout à coup ne désarme
> Honte à ceux qui n'ont pas de larmes
> Pour un chant dans la rue une fleur dans les prés

C'est extrait d'une poésie d'Aragon, « Ce que dit Elsa ». Mais Louis Aragon n'utilisait pas la ponctuation, donc je crois c'était une question rhétorique d'Elsa ou au moins quelque chose qui est proche à une question… Que pensez-vous ? Merci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ainsi*, et toute une série d'autres adverbes (peut-être, aussi, du moins, à peine, sans doute, pour n'en citer que quelques uns), entraînent une inversion clitique ou complexe quand ils apparaissent en tête de proposition, **dans un registre soutenu uniquement**.

Lorsqu'aucun sujet nominal n'est utilisé, on a une inversion clitique simple :

```
Sans doute aurait-il su résoudre ce meurtre sans ton aide
À peine était-elle arrivée qu'elle a entendu le bruit de la foule
Ainsi purent-ils pratiquer des dissections
```

Et quand un sujet nominal est présent, on a une inversion complexe :

```
Sans doute le célèbre détective aurait-il su résoudre ce meurtre sans ton aide
À peine Cassandre était-elle arrivée qu'elle a entendu le bruit de la foule
Ainsi les étudiants purent-ils pratiquer des dissections
```

Par contre l'inversion stylistique est interdite dans ce genre de phrase :

```
*À peine était arrivée Cassandre qu'elle a entendu le bruit de la foule
```

On peut éviter cette inversion en utilisant *que* après l'adverbe ou en plaçant ce dernier autre part dans la phrase :

```
Sans doute qu'il aurait su résoudre ce meurtre sans ton aide
Elle était à peine arrivée qu'elle a entendu le bruit de la foule
Ils purent (ainsi) pratiquer (ainsi) des dissections (ainsi)
```

Tous les adverbes ne permettent pas l'utilisation de *que*, cependant. C'est usuel avec *sans doute* et *peut-être*, mais impossible avec ainsi ou aussi, et possible mais uniquement dans des registres très familiers avec *à peine*.

Dans un registre familier, on voit maintenant apparaître *peut-être* et *sans doute* en tête de proposition sans ajout de *que* (p'têt il aurait préféré l'autre ?), mais c'est pour l'instant toujours minoritaire.

Cette inversion n'est pas porteuse de sens, il s'agit juste d'un reliquat d'une ancienne règle de grammaire qui forçait le verbe à apparaître en deuxième position dans un proposition, tout comme l'inversion dans les questions. Cette grammaire fossile a été formalisée dans les registres soutenus de la langue classique alors qu'elle était en train de disparaître de la langue courante. C'est surtout maintenant un marqueur de style.

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! C'est très clair, juste un petit doute : dans la phrase qui précède celle que j'ai mise partiellement en gras, l'inversion n'a pas été utilisé parce que le sujet de sa proposition principale était une proposition, "ce qui est dit des éléphants dans l’Histoire des Animaux" ?

Comment: @Evgeniy exactement, oui.